# ConstraintLayout clones dimension of other item

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My Problem:

I am trying to accomplish a Master-Detail-Layout with a ConstraintLayout.

My layout file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="@string/preferences"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mainFragment"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/detailsFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="300dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/mainFragment"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to accomplish, that the left FrameLayout is spreading between 300-400dp and the right FrameLayout is filling the remaining space. Can this be accomplished or do I have to resort to setting a fixed width for the left layout? The following blueprint showcases my problem. The right FrameLayout just copies the dimension of the left layout.

[image: Blueprint]

Comment: Why not use linearLayout inside contraintLayout ? That way you can get equal width for both layout.

Comment: If you want right layout to fill entire space, how do you expect left layout to determine value "between 300-400 dp"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the fact that you have used a chain. In order for this layout to work properly replace the `mainFragment` with following code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_min="300dp" />
```

Changes: changing the right constraint to fit to parent (instead of chaining with the `detailsFragment`) and adding horizontal bias, so that it start at the left edge. You can also remove the chain style from the `detailsFragment`.

Pro tip: chain styles should be defined only in the view that is on the most left and/or top side of the screen. Other chain styles are simply ignored.